# AWQL: Error in While fetch BiddingStrategyType in CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I want to fetch BiddingStrategyType, BiddingStrategyName etc. Please look into this. I have included following class:

```
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsSession;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsSessionBuilder;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\Reporting\v201710\ReportDownloader;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\Reporting\v201710\DownloadFormat;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\ReportSettingsBuilder;
use Google\AdsApi\Common\OAuth2TokenBuilder;
```

and run following awql :

```
SELECT Cost,CampaignId,Date,BiddingStrategyType,CampaignName FROM CRITERIA_PERFORMANCE_REPORT WHERE Status IN [ENABLED, PAUSED] DURING YESTERDAY;
```

---

> **Fatal error**: Uncaught exception 'Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201710\cm\ApiException' with message 'Details: [fieldPath: BiddingStrategyType; trigger: Invalid predicate name: BiddingStrategyType; errorString: SelectorError.INVALID_PREDICATE_FIELD_NAME]' in /var/www/html/crm2017/application/third_party/Googleadwords/googleads-php-lib/src/Google/AdsApi/AdWords/Reporting/v201710/ReportDownloader.php:169 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/crm2017/application/third_party/Googleadwords/googleads-php-lib/src/Google/AdsApi/AdWords/Reporting/v201710/ReportDownloader.php(127): Google\AdsApi\AdWords\Reporting\v201710\ReportDownloader->makeReportRequest(Array) #1 /var/www/html/crm2017/application/libraries/My_adwords.php(97): Google\AdsApi\AdWords\Reporting\v201710\ReportDownloader->downloadReportWithAwql('SELECT Cost,Cam...', 'CSV', Object(Google\AdsApi\AdWords\ReportSettings))

---

Query works without **BiddingStrategyType**.

Big Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found answer of above error. Correct AWQL query is :

```
SELECT Cost,CampaignId,BiddingStrategyType,CampaignName FROM CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT DURING YESTERDAY
```

BiddingStrategyType entity belongs to CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT not to CRITERIA_PERFORMANCE_REPORT.